# how to find specific digit values in a text file of one column?

Tags: python

```
for line in fname:
    fields = line.rstrip("\n").split()
    dc = refindall('0.8|0.9).group()
    samples = line
   sys.stdout.writelines(samples)
```

I got another problem with finding a specific float(digit ( 0.8 and 0.9) value in each line of one column text file. Secondly,  if it finds this line, it should  be deleted. Here is my code:

Comment: In the above code,  am trying to find lines that are equal to 0.8. It is a one-column text file.

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of errors in your code:

- There is a missing dot between re and findall.
- The dot in the regular expression means "match any character".
- Your string is not terminated correctly because there is a missing quote.
- re.findall takes two parameters. You seem to be providing only one.
- re.findall returns a list of strings. A list doesn't have a method called 'group'.
- The code is not indented correctly.

However there's no need for regular expressions here. Try this list comprehension instead:

```
lines = [line for line in lines if not (line == '0.8' or line == '0.9')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fname:
 fields = line.rstrip("\n").split()
dc = re.findall(r'0\.8|0\.9').group()
samples = line

sys.stdout.writelines(samples)
```

I think you weren't escaping the `.` in the regex.

EDIT: See Mark Byers post: You really do not need regexes for something like this.